# Python 3.4 : LXML web scraping

Tags: python, lxml

I am using the following code to try to return a list of tickers on that website.  The result of the code is an empty list. I copy the xpath from google chromium developer tools.  What am I doing wrong?

```
from lxml import html
import requests


url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'

resp = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(resp.text)

tickers = tree.xpath(r'//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a')

print(tickers)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers add in missing HTML elements that the HTML specification states are part of the model. `lxml` does not add those in.

The most common such element is the `<tbody>` element. Your document has no such element, but Chrome does and they put it in your XPath. Another such an element in the `<thead>` element; again, the original HTML is lacking it, but Chrome put it in and put the one `<tr>` row with `<th>` elements in it.

As such the *correct* XPath expression is:

```
tickers = tree.xpath(r'//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/a')
```

e.g. the second row in the table, first table cell in that row.

Note that `lxml` can load URLs directly; you don't really need to use `requests` in this specific case:

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'
>>> tree = html.parse(url)
>>> tree.xpath(r'//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/a')
[<Element a at 0x10445e628>]
>>> tree.xpath(r'//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/a')[0].text
'MMM'
>>> tree.xpath(r'//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/a')[0].attrib['href']
'https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:MMM'
```

If you wanted to extract all `<a>` elements in that first column, you'd have to remove the restriction on the `<tr>` element; your XPath picks all, remove the `[1]` to select *all*:

```
links = tree.xpath(r'//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tr/td[1]/a')
for link in links:
    print(link.text, link.attrib['href'])
```

Comment: Now what if I wanted the entire list of tickers?  there are multiple tr and corresponding td tags for each constituent of the sp500.

Comment: @AranFreel: simply remove the `[1]` restriction on the `tr` selector then.

Comment: What if I wanted to print the entire table using lxml... I am able to up to the third td tag but after that it returns nothing

Comment: @AranFreel: take into account only columns 1, 2, 3 and 6 have `<a>` link tags.

Comment: Any chance you would know how to return the entire row?

Comment: @AranFreel: remove the last few elements of the XPath expression; you'll get each `tr` element, and you can process that from there (including applying further XPath expressions to those elements).